# MYSQL проверка значения поля перед вставкой

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
create table team
(
    employee_id bigint not null,
    project_id  bigint not null,
    role_id     int    not null,
    foreign key (employee_id) references employee (id),
    foreign key (project_id) references project (id),
    foreign key (role_id) references role (id)
);
```

в которой хранятся id сотрудников `employee_id`

id проектов `project_id`

и id роли сотрудника в проекте `role_id`

Также имеется таблица `task`:

```
create table task
(
    id               bigint primary key auto_increment,
    name             varchar(30) not null,
    description      text,
    executor_id      bigint,
    labor_costs      int         not null,
    deadline         date        not null,
    status_id        int         not null,
    author_id        bigint,
    date_of_creation date        not null,
    update_time      date,
    foreign key (executor_id) references employee (id),
    foreign key (status_id) references task_status (id),
    foreign key (author_id) references employee (id),
```

`executor_id` в таблице `task` показывает id сотрудника, который выполняет поставленную задачу.

Выполнять поставленную задачу может только сотрудник,который участвует в проекте. Т.е перед вставкой значения в `executor_id` нужно направить запрос в `team` и посмотреть, участвует ли указанный `executor_id` в нашем `project_id`.

Как можно добиться такой проверки перед вставкой значения в бд?Т.е необходимо написать `check`

Comment: а как вы вставку делаете?

Comment: вам там точно `BIGINT` нужны  в идентификаторах, `INT UNSIGNED`, например, не достаточно? И как на счет первичного ключа в таблице `team` ?

Comment: а как task связан с `project_id` ?

Comment: @teran использую long, почитал, что у bigint диапазон числе такой же, как и long

Comment: @teran по executor_id можно направить запрос в task и получить все задачи этого пользователя.

Comment: диапазон диапазоном, а размер 4байта и 8. Если вам достаточно 4.5млрд значений - используйте инт. Прием если речь о ключах, то эта разница в 4байта пойдет не только в само поле, но и в каждый индекс. Есть хорошее простое правило - выбирать минимально достаточный тип данных.

Comment: относительно проверки я так и не понял. Вы пишите что при вставке надо взять исполнителя и проверить по project-id в teams, но не ясно, какое значение надо проверять для проекта? Таск то у вас к проекту не привязан никак, что за "наш project_id" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением функции (которая будет искать совпадение в другой таблице) и добавлением констрейнта с этой функцией

функция:

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkTeam (
  @field DATATYPE(?)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5) AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (ПОДЗАПРОС)
    return 'True'
  return 'False'
END
```

констрейнт:

```
ALTER TABLE task
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Team
CHECK (checkTeam(executor_id) = 'True')
```

код писался на скорую руку, но общую суть передал

Comment: а нельзя там как нить `returns tinyint` и сделать `return exists(..)` ?

Comment: да, можно вернуть любое нужное значение, я скорее набросал заготовку, а не полностью готовый вариант. О функциях можно посмотреть тут - https://oracleplsql.ru/functions-mysql.html